# Cannot get latest because the names of no-longer-existent files are too long

Tags: tfs

We had some .datasource files whose names were too long, and were actually no longer needed. My fellow developer deleted the files and committed to our TFS repo. I wiped out my local code and re-grabbed from the repo. The files are no longer in my local or in the repo.  If I try to right-click the .sln and 'get latest', I continue to get the error that the names of those no-longer-existent files are too long.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Just try to delete your current workspace and create a new one, then check if the issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

I did create a new workspace, but that was not enough.  To solve my issue I created a new workspace and pointed it deeper into the folder structure so that the path and name did not exceed the limit.